# How to use variables in an Oracle PL/SQL where clause

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I can't seem to get variables to work in an Oracle PL/SQL where clause.  I come from a Microsoft SQL Server background and there it was easy.  For example, what would be all steps needed to do something similar to the following?

```
declare @var int set @var = 1

select * from SomeTable where SomeField = @var
```

This doesn't seem like it should be hard in PL/SQL, but evidently it is.  :-/  I hear I need to use cursors and the like in PL/SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What do you want to do with the data that the SELECT returns?  If you just want to see it you don't need PL/SQL at all, just do this in SQL Plus:

```
variable var number
exec :var := 1

select * from SomeTable where SomeField = :var;
```

Or in a tool like SQL Developer or Toad, just do this:

```
select * from SomeTable where SomeField = :var;
```

and it will prompt you to enter the value for :var.

Comment: This is what the OP was asking for, at least, it looks very similar to what is shown in the SQLServer example.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like a good step in that direction.  Yes, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.  Any way to embed the variable in code vs having it appear in a pop-up prompt?

Answer (score 4):

The following code declares a variable `var` to use in the `WHERE` clause, and a variable `result` to put the result in then executes it inside a PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE
   var      INT := 1;
   result   INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT 123
     INTO result
     FROM DUAL
    WHERE var = 1;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (result);
END;
```

The `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` calls make it produce this DBMS output:

```
1
123
```

Comment: +1 Just need to clarify that this syntax is for a SELECT that must return exactly one row.

Comment: Thanks.  What about multiple rows?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare

  type t_rec is record
  (
  col1 number,
  col2 myTable.col2%type
  );
  v_rec t_rec;

  type t_tab is table of v_rec%type index by binary_integer;
  v_tab t_tab;

begin

  select col1, col2
  bulk collect into v_tab
  from myTable
  where col3 = 'BLAH';

  -- do something great with v_tab...

end;
```

Also know that if you try to select into (or bulk collect into) a variable and no rows are returned, you'll get a no_data_found exception, so you may want to handle that situation.

See [more here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CIHIEBJC) on pl/sql collections.  Above uses an associative array, but there are nested tables and varrays as well.  Again, see the link.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this

```
select * from sec_mainmenu where serno = '&MENU_ID';
```

When you run it, pl/sql will prompt for MENU_ID value.